# R : Join two dataframe on multiple conditions

Tags: r, date, join

I've got two dataframes. data.frame1 has information about patient ID, Visit Date, Visit number and treatment. data.frame2 has information about patient ID, Visit Date and a biological variable "Gly".
I would like to merge those two df in order to know which treatment the patient had when he had his biological test.

```
data.frame1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  Date1 = c(1, 5, 8, 12, 4, 9, 18, 22, 24, 33, 12, 22, 34, 56),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Treatment = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "C", "E")
)

data.frame2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  Date2 = c(1, 8, 20, 24, 34, 12, 41, 56),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Gly = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.1, 0.9, 1.4, 1.0, 1.8, 0.8)
)
```

(And no the Num_Visit don't match)

I've been looking around and tried this:

```
result <- data.frame1 %>%
  left_join(data.frame2, by = "ID") %>%
  group_by(ID, Date1) %>%
  filter(between(Date2, lag(Date1), lead(Date1, default = last(Date1)))) %>%
  summarise(Gly = first(Gly))
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I would like to have a data frame with a Date2, the matching biological variable "Gly" for this date and also a matching treatment for this date. It would look :

```
data.frame3 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  Date2 = c(1, 8, 20, 24, 34, 25, 41, 57),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Gly = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.1, 0.9, 1.4, 1.0, 1.8, 0.8),
  Treatment = c("A", "B", "E", "A", "A", "D", "C", "E")
)
```

Comment: Can you describe in words what you want in your output?

Comment: Is it clearer now ? feel free to tell me if it needs more explanation !

Comment: Is the Date2 variable correct for ID = 3?  Should it be 12, 41, 56 instead?

Comment: Yes, My bad, you're absolutely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data.table solution using rolling joins.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  Date = c(1, 5, 8, 12, 4, 9, 18, 22, 24, 33, 12, 22, 34, 56),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Treatment = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'E', 
                'E', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'E')
)

df2 <- data.table(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  Date = c(1, 8, 20, 24, 34, 12, 41, 56),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Gly = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.1, 0.9, 1.4, 1.0, 1.8, 0.8)
)

setkey(df1, ID, Date)
setkey(df2, ID, Date)
result <- df1[df2, .(ID, Date2 = Date, Num_Visit = i.Num_Visit, Gly, Treatment), 
              roll = TRUE, rollends = TRUE]

   ID Date2 Num_Visit Gly Treatment
1:  1     1         1 1.1         A
2:  1     8         2 1.3         B
3:  2    20         1 1.1         E
4:  2    24         2 0.9         A
5:  2    34         3 1.4         A
6:  3    12         1 1.0         D
7:  3    41         2 1.8         C
8:  3    56         3 0.8         E
```

Comment: Hey CPB ! 
Thank you for your time !
It works for me that's really cool !! thank you very much !! 
I'll try it on the bigger dataset and give your a feedback after that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one option how to do this with dplyr:

```
# Data preparation
data.frame1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  Date1 = c(1, 5, 8, 12, 4, 9, 18, 22, 24, 33, 12, 22, 34, 56),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  Treatment = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "E", "E", "A", "A", "D", "D", "C", "E")
)

data.frame2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  Date2 = c(1, 8, 20, 24, 34, 12, 41, 56),
  Num_Visit = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Gly = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.1, 0.9, 1.4, 1.0, 1.8, 0.8)
)

# Left join the data frames
merged_df <- left_join(data.frame2, data.frame1, by = c("ID", "Num_Visit"))

# Coalesce the Treatment columns from both data frames
merged_df %>%
  select(ID, Date2, Num_Visit, Gly, Treatment)


  ID Date2 Num_Visit Gly Treatment
1  1     1         1 1.1         A
2  1     8         2 1.3         A
3  2    20         1 1.1         B
4  2    24         2 0.9         B
5  2    34         3 1.4         E
6  3    12         1 1.0         D
7  3    41         2 1.8         D
8  3    56         3 0.8         C
```

Comment: Hey Isaac, thank you for taking the time !
I'm sorry if it wasn't clear in my question, but the Visit number does not match. Every subject didn't have a blood test at every visit. I had tried that on the full dataset but because it doesn't match i loose a lot of data.

For example, at Date2 = 8, subject 1 should have Treatment = B, and at Date2=20, subject 2 should have Treatment = E

Thank you for your answer, but i think there is a something more to add about the Date

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it requires a [rolling join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html#rolling-joins).

I assume `Gly` is a test performed on a date, which then triggers a particular `Treatment` performed on the test date or later.

This can be done using `dplyr` to perform rolling join to match the treatment with the latest test.

```
# Prepare a test data frame and treatment data frame.
df_treatment <- data.frame1 |>
    select(ID, Treatment_Date = Date1, Treatment)

df_test <- data.frame2 |>
    select(ID, Test_Date = Date2, Num_Visit, Gly)


# Join to match treatment with latest test.
result <- df_test |>
    left_join(
        y = df_treatment,
        join_by(ID == ID, closest(Test_Date <= Treatment_Date))
    ) |>
    select(ID, Test_Date, Treatment_Date, Num_Visit, Gly, Treatment)


# result
  ID Test_Date Treatment_Date Num_Visit Gly Treatment
1  1         1              1         1 1.1         A
2  1         8              8         2 1.3         B
3  2        20             22         1 1.1         E
4  2        24             24         2 0.9         A
5  2        34             NA         3 1.4      <NA>
6  3        12             12         1 1.0         D
7  3        41             56         2 1.8         E
8  3        56             56         3 0.8         E
```